Website not getting indexed with Google
Hello my website is not being indexed by Google. In Google Lighthouse it says:
Page is blocked from indexing

Blocking Directive Source X-Robots-Tag: none

However I cannot find anything that could be causing the blocking. There is nothing in the .htaccess file that would point to anything and I don't have a robots.txt file and in the head of the pages I have:
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
<meta name="GOOGLEBOT" content="INDEX, FOLLOW" />

If you want to take a look the website is the-ropewalk.co.uk and is built using Craft CMS 3x. It's not a new site at all. It's about 4 years old and it was indexed at some point so something has changed. I did a full search on the site and indeed some of the templates used for the shop had robots set to no-follow but those were only used on the shop and not form the rest of the site or home page. I hyave changed those but still no joy.
Is there any settings that CraftCMS has that I might have accidentally set that might mean the site is not visible to Google?
What else should I check please?
Any pointers would be helpful.
Thank you.

Craft will set a X-Robots-Tag: none header for front end requests, if any of the following are true:

The disallowRobots general config setting has been set to true in your config/general.php file

The request URL includes a valid token (as per the tokenParam config setting (default is 'token').

The request URL includes a valid preview param x-craft-preview or x-craft-live-preview (note: this only applies for Craft 4.12+ and 5.4+, which are upcoming releases at the time of writing this).


If neither of these are the case, you might have a plugin installed that is setting the X-Robots-Tag: none header. For example, I believe SEOMatic will set it if Craft's devMode config setting is set to true (which should not be the case for sites in production, for a plethora of reasons).

Thanks very much for your reply. It helped very much. disallowRobots wasn't set to true and I didn't have any plugins that interfered with devMode. In general.php I had 'devMode' => false when maybe it should have been $isProd (not sure if that made a difference) but what I think was the problem was in .env (which I didn't realise) I had ENVIRONMENT=dev when it should be ENVIRONMENT=production. It is now being indexed. Your pointers set me on the right path.

@cannon303 Ah, happy to hear that you sorted it out! Getting those environments mixed up is a common gotcha for sure.

I like to ->disallowRobots(App::env('CRAFT_DISALLOW_ROBOTS') ?? false) on config/general.php then add CRAFT_DISALLOW_ROBOTS=true to .env

@LeoLeoncio Env vars prefixed with CRAFT_ will actually override whatever is in your general.php file, so in practice the above is completely redundant – i.e. if you removed disallowRobots from your config file altogether (the default is false) and had CRAFT_DISALLOW_ROBOTS=true in your .env file in applicable environments, you'd have the exact same result. See https://craftcms.com/docs/5.x/configure.html#environment-overrides

Here's how I approach this (without seomatic)
.env
CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT=dev

CRAFT_DEV_MODE=true
CRAFT_DISALLOW_ROBOTS=true

config/custom.php
<?php

use craft\helpers\App;

$isProd = in_array(App::env('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT'), ['prod', 'production', 'live']);

return [
    'isProd' => $isProd
];

_layout.twig
{% set isprod = craft.app.config.custom.isProd ?? false %}
inside <head></head>
{{ not isprod ? tag('meta', {
    name: 'robots',
    content: 'noindex'
}) }}
{{ not isprod ? tag('meta', {
    name: 'googlebot',
    content: 'noindex'
}) }}

config/routes.php
<?php

return [
    'robots.txt' => ['template' => 'routes/robots.txt']
];

templates/routes/robots.txt.twig
{% set isprod = craft.app.config.custom.isProd ?? false %}
{% header "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" %}
{% if isprod %}
# live
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /cpresources/
Disallow: /cache/
sitemap: https://my-site.com/sitemap.xml
{% else %}
# lower env
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
{% endif %}

